# Lodash - Show changed properties of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I have a comparison function that checks if the user has changed any property values in the **objects** like this.

```
private checkForChanges(): boolean {
    if (_.isEqual(this.definitionDetails, this.originalDetails) === true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

this works great, however now I want to console.log changes which property is changed if there are any changes.

I've tried this:

```
console.log(_.difference(_.keys(this.originalDetails), _.keys(this.definitionDetails)));
```

but I always get `[]` so I assume my syntax is wrong.

What's the correct way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What version of lodash are you using?

Comment: @Meir using version 4.17.4

Comment: Do you want to compare the existence of property names in these two objects, or the value of these properties? Right now it is the first one if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Philipp I want to compare the values (I know the property exists, the user can only change it's value).

Comment: did you required to using lodash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `_.isEqual` might return false if the values changed, this can happen even if the keys stayed the same.

For example: `{x: 11, y: 12}, and {x: 11, y: 13}` will return false though they still have the same keys.

Your `_.difference()` compares the keys.

To get the keys that changed you'll need to implement your own function:

```
function changedKeys(o1, o2) {
  var keys = _.union(_.keys(o1), _.keys(o2));
  return _.filter(keys, function(key) {
    return o1[key] !== o2[key];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function will return every key that is changed. Meir solution does not worked for me. His solution will return any array value whether is not changed. So, I have tweaked it a bit

```
function(o1, o2) {
  var keys = _.union(_.keys(o1), _.keys(o2));
  return _.filter(keys, function(key) {
    return !_.eq(o1[key].toString(), o2[key].toString());
  })
}
```

Comment: Oops... doesn't account for null values. Use this instead: `return !_.eq(_.toString(o1[key]), _.toString(o2[key]));` (bearing in mind that null values and empty strings would be treated as equivalent with this approach).

Comment: @JohnRix that approach didn't worked for the properties that return null for me. So, I tried to use this approach, for instance those values which returns 'null' for the strings